# How can I test which icon my notifyIcon is using?

Tags: c#, testing, if-statement, timer, icons

I am having issues testing which icon my notifyIcon is using.

I have a notifyicon instantiated for my program. When the program runs I assign an icon to it in my code.

```
public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        notifyIcon1.Icon = Properties.Resources.LogoIcon;
    }
```

I have 2 buttons, one which starts my timer, and 1 which stops my timer. The timer event is suppose to check which icon is currently being used and switch it to the other option, but it doesn't work using my test.

```
Timer miniClock = new Timer();

    private void btnStartTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        miniClock.Interval = 1000;
        miniClock.Tick += new EventHandler(MiniClockEventProcessor);
        miniClock.Start();
    }

    private void MiniClockEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        if (notifyIcon1.Icon == Properties.Resources.AlertIcon)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Icon = Properties.Resources.LogoIcon;
        }
        else
            notifyIcon1.Icon = Properties.Resources.AlertIcon;

    }

    private void btnStopTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        miniClock.Stop();
        btnTest.Enabled = true;
    }
```

The frustrating part is when I start the timer, it will change the icon, but my test fails and it will only switch the icon in the else statement because there's no criteria to it except that it fails the if statement? How can I test which icon is currently being used, and then switch the icon to it's counterpart on the timer event call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easier to relay on some `state` then to `Icon` itself. 
I imagine that yo setup `AlertIcon` or `LogonIcon`, based on some event, or on some changed state notification. It's better to have somewhere the simple `bool` statevariable that indicates what happens.

For example , to explain what am I talking about, is a *pseudocode* :

```
private void MiniClockEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
   if (!IsAlertState)
   {
       notifyIcon1.Icon = Properties.Resources.LogoIcon;
   }
   else
       notifyIcon1.Icon = Properties.Resources.AlertIcon;

}

private bool IsAlertState {get;set}
```

On recived *alert* the property `IsAlertState = true`.

Something like this.

Comment: Great suggestion. I implemented the test based on a boolean changed in each run of the clock event and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: @FuzzEvans: Note that you'll want to cache the icons anyway. Otherwise you'll be loading them each time.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that every time you access an object directly from `Properties.Resources`, it actually reads it anew and creates a fresh object. Since `==` will test by reference and the references are not equal, your test fails each time.

The solution is to cache it, which you should be doing regardless for efficiency:

```
private static readonly Icon LogoIcon = Properties.Resources.LogoIcon;
private static readonly Icon AlertIcon = Properties.Resources.AlertIcon;

public Form1()
{            
    InitializeComponent();
    notifyIcon1.Icon = LogoIcon;
}
```

and

```
Timer miniClock = new Timer();

private void btnStartTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    miniClock.Interval = 1000;
    miniClock.Tick += new EventHandler(MiniClockEventProcessor);
    miniClock.Start();
}

private void MiniClockEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    if (notifyIcon1.Icon == AlertIcon)
    {
        notifyIcon1.Icon = LogoIcon;
    }
    else
        notifyIcon1.Icon = AlertIcon;

}

private void btnStopTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    miniClock.Stop();
    btnTest.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Though I understand what you're saying, I'm receiving an error trying to implement the above. Properties.Resources.LogoIcon' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'.

Comment: @FuzzEvans: Sorry, fixed the code. I forgot to define the type.

Comment: I appreciate your information as to why I can not test against the actual icon.

Comment: The type had to be set as "Icon", it wouldn't implicitly convert icons to bitmaps.

Comment: @FuzzEvans: Oh, you're using icons. Okay, then yes, `Icon` is the type :)